# No module named 'regression_testing.common' Python Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Repo is like this, with 2 folders for "individual modules" `regression_testing_package` and `regressin_testing_common` but both share the same namespace `regression_testing` both are managed with their own poetry configuration and both have their own sphinx documentation configuration.

In our python code, there are functions inside the `regression_testing_package` that use functions from `regression_testing_common` with imports like `from regression_testing.common.deprecation import deprecated` working without any issues

This is the folder structure

```
Root - repo is called regression_testing_package
  regression_testing_package (managed using poetry
    src
      regression_testing
        folder_a
        folder_b
    docs
      _source (all sphinx config/files are in here and publish ../ to docs)
  regression_testing_common
    src
      regression_testing
        common
    docs
      _source (all sphinx config/files are in here and publish ../ to docs)
```

When trying to build docs for `regression_testing_package` autodoc gives warnings as such `WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'pipelines' from module 'regression_testing.azure'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'regression_testing.common'`

So its been unable to build the docs for the pipeline module as the top of the file includes `from regression_testing.common.deprecation import deprecated` as i am working on deprecating some functions.

my `conf.py` contains the following (debug lines included)

```
import sys
import toml
from pathlib import Path

src_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[2] / 'src'
regression_testing_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[3] / 'regression_testing_common' / 'src' 

print(f"src_path exists: {src_path.exists()}, path: {src_path}")
print(f"regression_testing_path exists: {regression_testing_path.exists()}, path: {regression_testing_path}")

sys.path.insert(0, str(src_path))
sys.path.insert(1, str(regression_testing_path))

os.system("pip list")
```

And when running `make html` I can see from the 2 print statements that the path being added does indeed point to the `src` folder for both modules

```
src_path exists: True, path: C:\Users\Karl.Hudgell\Documents\Work\HE\regression-testing-package\regression_testing_package\src
regression_testing_path exists: True, path: C:\Users\Karl.Hudgell\Documents\Work\HE\regression-testing-package\regression_testing_common\src
```

the `pip list` command also seems to show the module is installed

```
PyYAML                        6.0.1
recommonmark                  0.7.1
regression-testing-common     0.1.2
regression-testing-package    3.0.9a1  C:\Users\Karl.Hudgell\Documents\Work\HE\regression-testing-package\regression_testing_package
reportlab                     4.0.7
requests                      2.31.0
```

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the docs to generate being able to see the functions in `regression-testing-common`

Comment: If you print out the value of PYTHONPATH FROM inside conf.py, near the os.system() call above, you can check what paths Sphinx has access to when it runs. I sometimes try to import the problem model in conf.py as well. Not a solution, but I find it helps with debugging "can't import" errors for autodoc.

Answer (score 0):

Delete those sys.path.insert() hacks.
Ensure the PYTHONPATH env var is setup properly *before* starting the interpreter or documentation tools.

Use python -m site to help debug config issues.

Comment: Ok, so from what you have said, I understand...

remove the hacks from conf.py
create an envvar called PYTHONPATH and point it to the Root of the repo? so it can traverse up and into both modules in the repo?
rerun the make html and see what happens?

Comment: Have set `PYTHONPATH = "C:\Users\Karl.Hudgell\Documents\Work\HE\regression-testing-package\regression_testing_package\src;C:\Users\Karl.Hudgell\Documents\Work\HE\regression-testing-package\regression_testing_common\src"` but still get the same error?

Comment: `python -m site` returns ```sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Karl.Hudgell\\Documents\\Work\\HE\\regression-testing-package\\regression_testing_package',
    'C:\\Users\\Karl.Hudgell\\Documents\\Work\\HE\\regression-testing-package\\regression_testing_package\\src',
    'C:\\Users\\Karl.Hudgell\\Documents\\Work\\HE\\regression-testing-package\\regression_testing_common\\src',``` (have removed some stuff)